# Twitter typeahead hidden field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, typeahead.js

I am using [twitter typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) to suggest a list of books to users on a search page. It all works as expected however I would now like to add another value to a hidden field.

Most of the tutorials I am looking at seem out dated.

My html form is as follows;

```
<form id="search" action="<?php echo URL; ?>books/itemView?id=" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" class="typeahead" id="demo"/>
<input type="text" name="isbn" type="hidden" class="typeahead" id="isbn"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="">
</form>
```

I am able to retrieve a list of suggestions from my json file. I am also able to click one of these and select it. This places the `id` in my input field. I would also like to place the `isbn` in the hidden field, how is this possible.

My JS is below;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = 'http://localhost/logintest/'; 

var books = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('title'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 3,
  prefetch: {
    url: url+'books.json',
    ttl: 0, 
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(book) {                         
        return { 
        id: book.id,
        title: book.title,
        author: book.author,
        isbn: book.isbn
        }; 
        });
    }
  }
});

books.initialize();

$('.demo .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'id', // displays the id in search bar once selection made
  engine: Handlebars,
  templates: {
    header: '<h1>Name</h1>',
    empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
      'no results found',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
       <strong>{{title}}</strong>
  },
  engine: Handlebars,
  source: books.ttAdapter() 
});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK turns out this is the answer, add this below the typeahead function

```
$('input.query').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {   
console.log(datum['empID']); 
});
```

Change empID to whatever you wish to log.